# Python: How to select a dropdown menu and download pdfs that are found in a .asp webpage?

Tags: python, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to write a program that will download all of the pdf files from a website. The problem is the link to the pdfs that I want to download are accessed by clicking on a drop down menu, which takes me to a .asp webpage.

Here's the website: http://www.k12.wa.us/safs/reports.asp?_sm_au_=iVVHQ2PsHsSjZNFj

```
<form action="data/reportformatter.asp" method="POST">
  <p><select name="District Name" size="1">
    <option selected="" value="State Summary">Select from the following list</option>
    <option>State Summary </option>
    <option>Aberdeen </option>
    <option>Adna </option>
    <option>Almira </option>
  </select> <input type="SUBMIT" value="Search" align="left"></p>
</form>
```

I want to select "Aberdeen" and download:

```
<a href="/safs/rep/enr/1516/14005t.pf">Report 1735T Special Education </a></td>
```

If you could explain to me why the .asp URL doesn't change when I select the different school districts (e.g. Aberdeen, Adna, etc.) and the direction I should go to get around this.